# Colorful Squares Python Program Using Nested Loops with Turtle

Tags: python-3.x, turtle-graphics

I'm trying to create a program in python that draw columns and rows of squares. There can only be 3 rows and 3-12 columns. The user must input how many columns they want and what 3 colors they want the rows to be. I'm struggling with how to line up the rows underneath each other and how to make it centered on the screen. I'm also struggling with how to make each row a different color. Any suggestions would help. Thank you! 
This is what I have so far.

```
import turtle


ROWS = 3
OFFSET = 10
cols = int(input('How many columns to display (3-12)? '))

color1 = input('What is the first color? ')
color2 = input('What is the second color? ')
color3 = input('What is the third color? ')

if cols < 3 or cols > 12:
  print('Error! Number of columns must be in range of 3 to 12.')

elif color1 == color2 or color1 == color3:
  print('Error! All the colors must be different!')
elif color2 == color1 or color2 == color3:
  print('Error! All the colors must be different!')
elif color3 == color1 or color3 == color2:
  print('Error! All the colors must be different!')
else:
  for r in range(ROWS):
    y = turtle.ycor() - 115
    x = turtle.xcor() 
    turtle.penup()
    turtle.goto(x,y)
    turtle.pendown()
    turtle.fillcolor(color1)
    turtle.begin_fill()
    for c in range(cols):
      x = turtle.xcor() + 95
      y = turtle.ycor()
      turtle.penup()
      turtle.goto(x,y)
      turtle.pendown()
      for side in range(4):
        turtle.forward(50)
        turtle.left(90)
    turtle.end_fill()
```

[Example of what it needs to look like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NZ4GL.png)

Answer (score 0):

Your input verification needs work and hopefully the example below will help with that.  As far as centering on the screen, you need to make the code dynamic, so constants like:

```
y = turtle.ycor() - 115
x = turtle.xcor() + 95
turtle.forward(50)
```

Aren't doing you any good.  You need to compute these values based on the number of columns, the width of the window, and the size of your borders and gaps.

Since you should be doing this lab yourself, I'm going to provide a working example that won't be of direct use to you as it uses *stamping* and your problem appears to be based on *drawing*.  (One difference is where the turtle is when it initiates drawing a box.)  But you'll be able to see the calculations necessary to properly center and line up your boxes:

```
from turtle import Screen, Turtle

ROWS = 3
CURSOR_SIZE = 20  # base unit for cursor resizing

columns = -1

while not 3 <= columns <= 12:
    columns = int(input('How many columns to display (3-12)? '))
    if not 3 <= columns <= 12:
        print('Error! Number of columns must be in range of 3 to 12.')

color = input('What is the first color? ')

colors = [color]

while color in colors:
    color = input('What is the second color? ')
    if color in colors:
        print('Error! All the colors must be different!')

colors.append(color)

while color in colors:
    color = input('What is the third color? ')
    if color in colors:
        print('Error! All the colors must be different!')

colors.append(color)

screen = Screen()

# assumptions: there is a one box size border on each side and
# the gap between boxes, vertical and horizontal, is 1/2 box

# dimensions are based on number of columns and window width
box_size = screen.window_width() / ((columns - 1) * 1.5 + 3)

turtle = Turtle()
turtle.hideturtle()
turtle.shape('square')
turtle.shapesize(box_size / CURSOR_SIZE)  # make the turtle our standard box
turtle.penup()

y = box_size * 1.5  # y center of top-most boxes

for row in range(ROWS):
    turtle.fillcolor(colors[row])

    x = -box_size * (columns * 3/4 - 3/4)  # x center of left-most boxes

    turtle.goto(x, y)

    for column in range(columns):

        turtle.stamp()

        x += box_size * 1.5  # move by a box and a gap

        turtle.setx(x)

    y -= box_size * 1.5  # move by a box and a gap

screen.exitonclick()
```

Note how all the user's inputs have been corrected and/or redundancy checked before the code moves onto drawing boxes:

[image]

If you haven't learned about arrays like `colors` yet, you should still be able to do the color checks and assignments, it'll just take additional code.

Comment: Thank you! That helped me so much. It only took 7 and a half hours, but sometimes that's what it takes. You helped me more than my teacher did. I really appreciate it.